# How to parse the json array in android without KEY:VALUE pair?

Tags: android

I have following output from server. How to parse it in android? Need help.

```
 [["1","shopknock","0","0","22","18.5123","73.8563"],["2","Food Shopei","231","1","17","18.5122","73.8562"],["10","Ccd","0","0","22","18.5211","73.857"]]
```

Comment: make sure its a valid json. if its  a json array you can get the value based on the index

Answer (score 3):

`[` represents a json array node

To parse

```
JSONArray jr = JSONArray("your json string");
for(int j=0;j<jr.length;j++)
{ 
JSONArray jr1 = (JSONArray)jr.getJSONArray(j);
for(int i=0;i<jr1.length();i++)
{
     String value = (String)jr1.get(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSONObject and JSONArray class. Go through the below link to clear your concept on these:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Then, go through the below tutorial, it provides a class called ServiceHandler.java to handle your json parsing. It is quite easy:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/